# Unable to create a symlink to a file

Tags: symbolic-link

I am not able to create a simple symlink here. When I tried the command

```
sudo ln –s /home/vivek/Downloads/drush/drush /home/vivek/Documents/
```

where drush is a file inside the folder named drush, I get the following error,

```
ln: accessing `–s': No such file or directory
```

Then I tried giving the filename in the target path,

```
sudo ln –s /home/vivek/Downloads/drush/drush /home/vivek/Documents/drush
```

for which I got this,

```
ln: target `/home/vivek/Documents/drush' is not a directory
```

I even tried getting into the target directory (i.e. `/home/vivek/Documents`)   and typed the following command

```
sudo ln –s /home/vivek/Downloads/drush/drush
```

But still got the same error message as follows

```
ln: accessing `–s': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it expecting a target directory while I am only trying to create a symlink for a file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your dash character (`–`) is different from the minus character (`-`) used to specify options. (Probably copied code from a web page.)

Try with `-s`.

Since it does not recognize `–s` as an option it tries to look for a file.

Comment: To be precise: The symbol used for options is a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), different from both dash and the (typographical) minus.